# ERROR CODE 1146 DE MYSQL COMO LO ARREGLO

Tags: mysql

Alguna solución? me sale este error:

> `Error Code: 1146. Table 'base_de_datos_prueba.base_de_datos_prueba' doesn't exist`

```
INSERT INTO base_de_datos_prueba (Code, Contents, Value, Warehouse) VALUES('OMN7','Rocks',180,3)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que falta el nombre de la tabla. ¿Tu tabla se llama `base_de_datos_prueba` o ese es el nombre de la base de datos?

Comment: Es el nombre de la base de datos

Comment: Y a que tabla le queres agregar los datos?

Comment: Pues eso, debes indicar en qué tabla de la base de datos quieres insertar, no se inserta directamente en la base de datos. Algo así: **`INSERT INTO base_de_datos_prueba.AQUIELNOMBREDELATABLA (Code, Contents, Value, Warehouse) VALUES('OMN7','Rocks',180,3);`** o bien: **`INSERT INTO AQUIELNOMBREDELATABLA (Code, Contents, Value, Warehouse) VALUES('OMN7','Rocks',180,3);`** si lo haces desde un contexto en el que ya estás conectado a esa base de datos.

Comment: intente como dijiste y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: ¿Seguro que esa tabla existe? ¿Qué muestra esta consulta: `SHOW TABLES FROM base_de_datos_prueba;`

Comment: Tene en cuenta que para agregar valores dentro de una tabla primero debe existir la tabla. En ese caso te recomendaria probar con "CREATE TABLE .... "